# Numpy: insert new elements in array by doing operations on columns (or rows) of NxM array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This may be a silly question, but I've just started using numpy and I have to figure out how to perform some simple operations.

Suppose that I have the 2x3 array

```
 array([{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3], 
         {"a":4, "b":5, "c":6}])
```

And that I want to perform some operations and insert new elements(d and e) in my array,

`d = a + b, e = b - c`

```
array([{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3, "d":3, "e":-1],
 {"a":4, "b":5, "c":6, "d":9, "e":-1}])
```

How can I perform such an operation using numpy library without foreach loop?

Thank's by advance...

Comment: Is this an array of dicts? Or a structured array? Or something else?

Comment: It's an array of dicts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you should use pandas.DataFrame for column-wise operations. If you strictly have to use numpy, this obviously does not solve your problem. However looking at the line of code you provided, the pandas library seems like the right choice. Here is an example for the problem you described.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}, {"a":4, "b":5, "c":6}])
df["d"] = df["a"] + df["b"]
df["e"] = df["b"] - df["c"]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  2  3  3 -1
1  4  5  6  9 -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array is a 1d, 2 element object dtype array that contains dictionaries:

```
In [26]: arr = np.array([{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}, {"a":4, "b":5, "c":6}])         
In [27]: arr                                                                    
Out[27]: array([{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}], dtype=object)
```

A list of dictionaries probably makes more sense:

```
In [28]: alist = [{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}, {"a":4, "b":5, "c":6}]                 
In [29]: alist                                                                  
Out[29]: [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}]
```

To act on those dictionaries you will just have to iterate over them.  The `whole-array` numpy operations work in numbers, not dictionaries or general Python objects.